# how to change width of custom tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

i am trying to custom tabs in action bar. it works fine in many devices but sometimes its width not set to match_parent. i have used textview as custom layout. i tried many things like i changed in style.xml

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    </style>`

but from upper solution my other layout become so stucked up. so if anyone know how to enlarge size of custom tab to match_parent than it will really help me thank 
you

[image: this is how it looks.]

==> this is my code from where i try to set textview to tabs

```
   TextView textView=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView.setText(tab_name);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setTextSize(20.0f);


            textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            textView.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            textView.setTypeface(customFont);

             actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setCustomView(textView)
                .setTabListener(this));
```

Comment: give equal padding from left and right to the layouts of these textviews

Comment: @AnshulTyagi it didn't work out . :(

Comment: Post your xml code and mention them. I'll edit for you

Comment: okay i will just edit my question

Comment: @AnshulTyagi i just updated my just have a look. thank you

Comment: Can't you use this `textView` in xml layout ?

Comment: no, i think it is better to use as java than xml. do i have to change it to xml?

Comment: no, leave it, just try to give size 13 to `TextView`

Comment: are you talking about textsize?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74249/discussion-between-anshul-tyagi-and-the3211).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlast i got solution to this..

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

this was my App theme at first so i changed it to :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        </style>
```

and included other style for Actionbar

```
 <style name="custom_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>


    </style>
```

and i set that action bar activity theme to custom theme. so whole app theme will be Apptheme but for that perticular activity i set custom_theme.

```
 <activity android:name=".abc" android:theme="@style/custom_theme" android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
```

i tried many ways but none work. so i implement this way.